# Why regexp does not find match

Tags: c#, regex, match, string-matching

Code

```
var tekst = "Sum km-ta 20% _48,15";
var rida = Regex.Match(tekst, @"(?si)Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>.*?)\s", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Does not find math. It looks like RegExp is correct but for unknown reason sum is not found.
How to get match 48,15 ?

Using C# in .NET 7

Comment: "*It looks like RegExp is correct but for unknown reason sum is not found.*" [Regex101 says your pattern doesn't match the numbers, nor does it capture "Sum".](https://regex101.com/r/GRZ6Ik/1)

Comment: Why Regex101 says Group kmta is empty? It must match to 48,15

Comment: I don't know but it suggests the pattern isn't correct.

Comment: It's because you've made the named capture group lazy. So empty match satisfies it.

Comment: I dont see this suggestion in your link. Where it is suggested so?

Comment: The fact that *it does not match* is what suggests that the pattern is incorrect.

Comment: I removed lazy mark ? in end of regex: __(?si)Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>.*)\s__  It still does not find match.

Comment: Your kmta match is non-greedy, and you require a whitespace after it. Try changing that final \s into a $

Comment: @Andrus you need to make last `\s` optional - there is no invisible characters at the end of you string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `kmta` group is lazy, so empty match is fine. You can try to limit what is allowed inside the group and remove laziness, also there is no invisible characters at the end of the string -  `(?si)Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>[\d,\.]*)(\s)?`:

```
var tekst = "Sum km-ta 20% _48,15";
var rida = Regex.Match(tekst, @"(?si)Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>[\d,\.]*)(\s)?", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var ridaGroup = rida.Groups["kmta"].Value; // 48,15
```

Also you can just remove laziness and make the `\s` optional: `(?si)Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>.*)\s?`

Comment: @Andrus it can be framework depended. I've used .NET 7 and it has found the match - [demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AKgKYAew+ASsQOYQA2AhmAKKkAOYxAztwJYB7KNwDc6AG7NswYgGtuwbAF5sAIgDKEALbZZWgLTBG2BJgCk2APoAWABwAaJAFZVYtJLDYwfACbGV1DRk+ACyjMAAxgAWABQy8sD2uHCqMQD8/ACUmloxlplpMQA63HqGjAXF3JWmZpUglSWV+YVpADx6RgB8ANpFPvZF+AC6AFSZVQWqSYFkAPLswILC+Op8UDT0xPTrxJluHl6+jADiYAIQ7MpHfvhnF+zcPaqdjKrD+ABqjPQQxCLYAD0gOwdkcTnQeAAnDFvH57pd9kA==)

Comment: In real code string was part of string. I added __* .__ to start and end of pattern. __(?si).*Sum(_)?(\skm-ta)?(\s)?(20%)?(:)?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmta>[\d,\.]*)(\s)?.*__ Is this ok?

Comment: @Andrus it is hard to tell. Without seeing at least some input variability it is hard to tell what pattern should be used.